# how to force wget to ignore certain redirects

Tags: redirect, wget

I am trying to wget a list of urls (images) some of them no longer exist and the host redirect to a generic "this image doesn't exist" page, of which I know the url of. I would like to wget the file unless it 302's to this domain, is it possible.

I can stop it getting the file if any redirects with the `--max-redirect=0` flag, but this may stop getting real images if I hit a mirror

Comment: Can you clarify what that has to do with https or htaccess?

Comment: @ShaneMadden oh sorry, it seems the title is from an old half edited post and was put in error, I will change it

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do this (`--exclude-domains` apparently doesn't work when it's a `302`) - are all the images from a specific host, is the mirror redirect problem likely to happen?

Comment: @ShaneMadden a lot are from flickr which redirects any non-existent link to this particular "image not found" image

Answer (score 1):

The only (really hacky) way I can imagine to accomplish this is to implement an HTTP proxy in front of `wget`, which can override the "image not found" with an error code so that you're not downloading it.

Any configurable proxy should be able to get this kind of behavior - for example, with Apache you could do something like:

```
ProxyRequests On
<Proxy http://example.com/path/to/image-not-found.jpg>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Proxy>
```